# Images overlapping with Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm currently using jQuery Masonry and the imagesLoaded plugin on a WordPress theme, but images are still overlapping when I load the page.

The layout displays well only when I resize the page but otherwise it still looks bad.

Here's a screenshot of the layout when the page loads:

[image: The "cards" are overlapping when they should not.]

Here's my code for now:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
   $('.gridContainer').imagesLoaded( function() {
    var doneMasonry = false;

    function doPostsMasonry() {

        if (doneMasonry) {
            return;
        }
        doneMasonry = true;
        var masonry = $(".post-list.row");

        var images = masonry.find('img');
        var loadedImages = 0;

        var debounceMasonryRefresh = jQuery.debounce(function () {
            masonry.data().masonry.layout();
        }, 500);

        function imageLoaded() {
            loadedImages++;
            if (images.length === loadedImages && masonry.data().masonry) {
                masonry.data().masonry.layout();
            }
        }

        images.each(function () {
            $(this).on('load', imageLoaded);
            debounceMasonryRefresh();
        });


        var items = $(".post-list.row .post-list-item");
        var index = items.length - 1;
        items.each(function () {
            $(this).css({
                width: $(this).css('max-width')
            })
        });
        if (masonry.length) {
            masonry.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.post-list-item',
                percentPosition: true,
                columnWidth: '.' + items.eq(index).attr('data-masonry-width')
            });
        }
    }

    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
        doPostsMasonry();
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
            doPostsMasonry();
        }
    })
   })
});
```

I also tried using the function `layoutComplete` (eg. `$('.div').on('layoutComplete', function {})`) but it does not work either.

You can have a look at the page live here: https://www.lesvoyagesdemma.fr/bonsplans

Comment: Where do you call your doPostsMasonry in the imagesLoaded function?

Comment: i'm triggering the whole script only after calling `imagesLoaded`. Also, using `debounceMasonryRefresh()` for each image.

Comment: Sounds like it's not quite working. If you put doPostsMasonry(); right before your only load check, the if (window.innerWidth >= 768) ... does it make a difference?

Comment: That helped, but the problem still displayed on low bandwith connections. I just changed the debounceMasonryRefresh() time to 3000ms. It's dirty, but at least, it works.